# Am I missing something in Rudin' PMA Theorems 2.38 - 2.40?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I'm reviewing Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis in studying for an Intro Exam for PhD program. I'm in Chapter 2, specifically theorems 2.38 - 2.40. Having independently done the proofs prior to these theorems, I am wondering why a simpler approach is not warranted.

Consider Theorem 2.38: If $\{I_n\}$ is a sequence of intervals in $R^1$, such that $I_n$ contains $I_{n+1}$ ($n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$), then infinite intersection of the sets $I_n$ is not empty.

By Rudin's definition of interval in definition 2.17, the interval is a closed set in $R^1$. Since $R^1$ is a metric space, the intervals $I_n$ are thus compact sets. So isn't Theorem 2.38 just the corollary to Theorem 2.36 directly above on the page (see below)? Why go through the proof Rudin uses to prove Theorem 2.38.

> **2.36  Theorem**: If $\{K_\alpha\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite
> subcollection of $\{K_\alpha\}$ is nonempty, then $\bigcap K_\alpha$
> is nonempty.
>
> [proof omitted]
>
> **Corollary**: If $\{K_n\}$ is a sequence of nonempty compact sets such that $K_n \supset K_{n+1}\, (n = 1, 2, 3, \dots)$, then $\bigcap K_n$ is
> not empty.

I must be missing something basic?

Comment: "Since R is a metric space" is not a valid argument: closed subset of a metric space need not be compact. // Welcome to Math.SE

Comment: For those that don't have the book can you add theorem 2.36.

Comment: Thanks Pavel M!! That's my misunderstanding - I mashed together Theorems 2.34 and 2.35, thinking a closed subset of a metric space is compact. In R^1 the set would have to be both closed and bounded to be compact.

Comment: At this point in the text, it hasn't been established that closed, bounded sets in $\Bbb R$ are compact.

Comment: Corollary to Theorem 2.36: If {K_n} is a sequence of nonempty compact sets such that K_n contains K_{n+1} (n=1,2,3, ...) then the infinite intersection of the K_n's is not empty.

Comment: Or even that (closed, bounded) intervals are compact. This is done in 2.40.

Comment: We never used Rudin's books to study in my university (at least back then), and some years after I graduated I needed to check some stuff for a calculus course I taught and I didn't find it comfortable for me...and upon reading this question and Rudin's book I know now why: his definitions (e.g., "interval") are sometimes quite different from almost any other books', theorem 2.36 is a particular case of a rather important characterization of *general* compact topological spaces, very handy for proving Tychonov's theorem but pretty weird in this particular spot, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio this is very late, but I fail to see how interval is defined in any unusual way. It's Definiton 2.17.

Answer (score 3):

Just to have an answer here: yes, something was amiss. It is very straightforward to prove that a nested sequence of nonempty compact sets has a common point. One could hope to get the [nested interval lemma](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~carother/cantor/Nested.html) from here, but ... first it must be proved that a closed bounded interval is compact, which is at least as hard as the nested intervals lemma itself. In fact Rudin uses the nested interval lemma in the proof that a closed bounded interval is compact.

Comment: The nested interval lemma looks a lot more basic than Heine-Borel.